# Why floating number is different every hundreds?

Tags: floating-point

I stumbled accross some precision "error" when using floating number in Python and when I wanted to play a little with it, I discovered an odd pattern.

This is the little floating issue:

```
1.15 * 100  # Returns 114.99999999999999
```

So I tried with `* 1`, then `* 10` and that number was correct (showing 15, not 14...).

But, when I ran a script to display the multiples of 10 for that number, this is what I found:

```
lvl = 1
for i in range(0, 15):
    lvl = lvl * 10
    1.15 * lvl
```

Showed the following:

```
11.5 # 10
114.99999999999999 # 100
1150.0 # 1.000
11500.0 # 10.000
114999.99999999999 # 100.000
1150000.0 # 1.000.000
11500000.0 # 10.000.000
114999999.99999999 # 100.000.000
1150000000.0 # 1.000.000.000
11500000000.0 # 10.000.000.000
114999999999.99998 # 100.000.000.000
1150000000000.0 # 1.000.000.000.000
11500000000000.0 # 10.000.000.000.000
114999999999999.98 # 100.000.000.000.000
1150000000000000.0 # 1.000.000.000.000.000
```

What bothers me, is that the floating number changes from 15 to 14 when the multiplier is "hundreds" of something (hundreds, hundreds of thousands, hundreds of millions, etc).

Why is that? Why hundreds?

Comment: By the way, the example code you show seems to be Python. IIRC Python have their own number implementation, which could be flawed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is not what is happening here. The behavior observed is a consequence of the ubiquitous IEEE-754 binary64 arithmetic.

Comment: In hexadecimal, the closest value in the IEEE-754 binary64 format to 1.15 is 0x1.2666666666666. See how the digits repeat? The bits of hexadecimal 666… are 011001100110… What happens is that, when you multiply by various powers of 10, the point where rounding must occur in the binary64 format (at the 53rd significant bit) lands in different places relative to those bits, sometimes rounding up (yielding an result like 11.5, 1150, and so on) and sometimes down. It is a bit curious why the pattern has a period of three, but it is surely just some normal number theoretic behavior.

Comment: In any case, the pattern will break as the power of 10 grows, because greater powers of 10 have more significant bits, and, when they pass 53 significant bits, the power itself will be rounded as you compute it, and the various roundings will interfere and disrupted the pattern.

Comment: Ah, the cause of the pattern issue might be that 5^3 is near 128, so the product is moving a different number of binades every third iteration, for the first few iterations. (After some number of iterations, the difference between 125 and 128 will disrupt this.)

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. Observe the greatest powers of two not greater than the numbers in the sequence: 2^3 for 11.5, 2^6 for 115, 2^10 for 1150,… These powers are 3, 6, 10, 13, 16, 20, 23, 26, 30,…, with differences 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3,… So the rounding is landing in two places where it rounds down and one where it rounds up, and then the accumulated effect of multiplying by 10 (8•1.25) causes a skip in the power, so you get a period of three.

Comment: Voted to reopen because the question specifically asks about the pattern and does not ask about why floating-point produces answers different from real-number arithmetic, and because the answer is reasonably interesting and illuminating about the details of floating-point arithmetic. I do not have time to write it up at the moment. Somebody else is welcome to do so using the information in the above comments. Otherwise, I may write it up when I have more time.

Comment: Correction: The pattern has two roundings up and one down, not vice-versa.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you so much for your answer. I'm late to thank you but it's very interesting what you answered (both as comment and answer) and it's truly interesting to understand that behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When 1.15 is converted to IEEE-754 binary64 format, the result is, in hexadecimal, 0x1.2666666666666. (1.15 is 23/20, and it has a repeating pattern in hexadecimal for the same reason that 2/3 has a repeating pattern in decimal.) Note that this number has 53 bits in its significand, including the final 0 bit—from the leading 1 to the low bit of the final 6, there are 53 bits.

This value is slightly below 1.15; it is 1.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375. When we multiply that by powers of 10, the real-number results are 11.4999…, 114.999…, and so on. The only way we can get a result in which the significant digits are 115 is if the multiplication rounds up when rounding the product to fit in the floating-point format.

Observe that 0x1.2666666666666 has a pattern that repeats every four bits. So, if we rounded this at the last bit, then at the second-to-last bit, then third-to-last, and so on, we would see a pattern repeating every four terms.

However, we multiply by 10, 100, 1000, and so on. Consider that log<sub>2</sub>10 is about 3.322, a little under 3⅓. (Equivalently, 10<sup>3</sup>=1000 is near 2<sup>10</sup>=1024.) So where powers of 10 lie relative to powers of 2 has a pattern repeating every three terms until the fractions add up:

- 2<sup>3</sup> ≤ 10<sup>1</sup> < 2<sup>4</sup>.
- 2<sup>6</sup> ≤ 10<sup>2</sup> < 2<sup>7</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>9</sup> ≤ 10<sup>3</sup> < 2<sup>10</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>13</sup> ≤ 10<sup>4</sup> < 2<sup>14</sup>, 4 more than previous.
- 2<sup>16</sup> ≤ 10<sup>5</sup> < 2<sup>17</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>19</sup> ≤ 10<sup>6</sup> < 2<sup>20</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>23</sup> ≤ 10<sup>7</sup> < 2<sup>24</sup>, 4 more than previous.
- 2<sup>26</sup> ≤ 10<sup>8</sup> < 2<sup>27</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>29</sup> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup> < 2<sup>30</sup>, 3 more than previous.
- 2<sup>33</sup> ≤ 10<sup>10</sup> < 2<sup>34</sup>, 4 more than previous.

Thus, until the approximation issue disrupts this pattern, the powers of ten form a “every fourth” bit pattern with a cycle of three powers of ten.

(I have omitted some details here—it is actually the powers of five that matter, since they influence the significant digits of the results, and it is those significant digits that must be rounded, not the powers of ten. But this is not a mathematical proof, and cannot be because the pattern does not continue long; it is merely a coincidence in a small region, so this explanation is merely intended to explain the coincidence intuitively.)

So, what we are seeing is that, in the cycle of three terms, two of them round up and produce significant digits of 115, and one of them rounds down and produces 114.999…. It is merely a coincidence and not a deep mathematical truth.

Comment: I automatically reached for the "is floating point math broken" duplicate that pops up at least once a week but then saw your reason for voting to reopen it as well as this answer. Certainly there are interesting questions that can be raised about exactly how floating-point math works that are not answered by that question.